# Area bounded by a parabola and its chord is equal to two-thirds of area of bounding paralellogram

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

Here AB|| CD and ABCD is a parallelogram . We need to show that the area covered by the both Parallelogram and the Parabola CDX is two thirds of that of the parallelogram ABCD.

Can anyone please help me to prove this?
[image]

Comment: What are you allowed to use?

Comment: Please state what tools are allowed here. ... Also, I believe you mean to say simply that *the area of the parabolic sector $CXD$ [not the area covered by parabola and parallelogram] is two-thirds the area of parallelogram $ABCD$.* After all, chord $\overline{CD}$ and point of tangency $X$ are enough to determine the area of the parallelogram. Point $A$ could be located anywhere on the tangent line, including places such that $\overline{AD}$ or $\overline{BC}$ cuts through the parabola; such a cutting-through would affect the area of the overlap, but not the area of the parallelogram.

Comment: You can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quadrature_of_the_Parabola#Geometric_proof) the classical proof by Archimedes.

Comment: I have done all basic courses in Mathematics. But please try to keep the answer as simple as possible.@amd

Answer (score 1):

Let  $y=ax^2$ be the parabola, with $(x_1, ax_1^2)$ and $(x_2, ax_2^2)$ the coordinates of the chord. The equation of the chord is then

$$y=kx+m_1=a(x_1+x_2)x - ax_1x_2$$

Let the side of the parallelogram parallel to the chord $y=kx +m_2$. Since it is tangential to the parabola, the discriminant of $a(x_1+x_2)x +m_2=ax^2$ is zero, which yield $m_2=-\frac{k^2}{4a}$.

The area of the enclosing parallelogram is then,

$$A_1 = (m_1-m_2)(x_2-x_1) = \left(- ax_1x_2+\frac{a^2(x_1+x_2)^2}{4a}\right)(x_2-x_1)
=\frac a4(x_2-x_1)^3\tag{1}$$

The area of the parabolic segment can be obtained with,

$$A_2 = \frac a2(x_1^2+x_2^2)(x_2-x_1)-\int_{x_1}^{x_2}  ax^2 dx=\frac a6(x_2-x_1)^3\tag{2}$$

where the first term is the area of the trapezoid under the chord and the integral accounts for the area under the parabola.

From (1) and (2), $A_2 = \frac23 A_1$, that is, the area bounded by the parabola and its chord is equal to two-thirds of the area of the bounding parallelogram.

Comment: I’m not so sure that a proof that uses integrals is quite right for a question tagged “algebra-precalculus“ and “conic sections.”

Comment: It may be a fair. But, algebra-precalculus does not offer formulas for the area of parabolic segments. It is sometimes cited as $\frac23A$, where $A$ is the area of enclosing rectangle, which is just the direct result of integration.